# Trying to create a stacked barchart from dataframe data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, bar-chart

I am trying to create a stacked bar-chart showing total marriages by months for each year between 2008 and 2015.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io
import requests
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
url = "https://data.code4sa.org/api/views/r4bb-fvka/rows.csv"
file=requests.get(url).content
c=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(file.decode('utf-8')))
```

Here I am adding the total number of marriages for each year then grouping by both Marriage Year and month to have the total number of marriages for each month

```
c['Total'] = c['MarriageYear']
months = c.groupby(['MarriageYear','MarriageMonth'])['Total'].count()
```

I think the index should be both Marriage Year and Marriage Month since I want the total of marriages for each month in every year???

```
months.set_index(['MarriageYear','MarriageMonth'])\
      .reindex(months.set_index('MarriageMonth').sum().sort_values().index, axis=1)\
      .T.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True,
              colormap=ListedColormap(sns.color_palette("GnBu", 10)), 
              figsize=(24,28))
```

If you do post any potential solutions or what I should look at again, please explain why/where I went wrong and how I should be approaching this

Comment: What are your x axis and y axis and stacked groups for this bar chart?

Comment: x-axis should be year and y should be total number of marriages in that given year

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
c.groupby(['MarriageYear', 'MarriageMonth']).size() \
 .unstack().plot.bar(stacked=True, colormap='GnBu', figsize=(12, 14))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, mind explaining this a bit, I get that you groupedby the data by year and month then calculated the number of marriages...a bit lost on the next line

Comment: @Emm I suggest you try each bit and look at the results.  Also, look up the method calls and see what the documentation tells you.  I've pointed you in the right direction with enough information to allow you to figure the rest out.

Comment: `\\` at the end of a Python line indicates that it should be continued on the next line.